# Google Chrome Extension Running Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an extension for Google Chrome and I realized that my extension will run twice if I include the following in the manifest:

```
"background":{"page": "popup.html","persistent": true},
```

However I need the .html file to run in the background in order to load data, if anymore information is required please do let me know.

Edit 1: I have only added the following scripts in HTML, if that gives a clue.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean with running twice?

Answer (score 0):

In the `popup.html` you might have included jquery.min.js twice. This will result running all `$(document).ready()` events twice

Comment: `<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script src="popup.js"></script>` I have double checked and made sure that I didn't do that.